# How to create an emissive (and reflective) line or curve in THREE.js

Tags: reflection, three.js, line

I have a series of curves in the format:

```
var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -5, 5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 5, -5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 10 )
] );
var points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 , linewidth:100} );
var curveObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(curveObject)
```

I want these to have a reflection visible on the surface of a shiny MeshPhong (material) Plane - preferably white. I can make the lines 'glow' using a BloomPass, however, I am more interested in producing a warped reflection on the surface.

Since LineBasicMaterial does not have an emissivity attribute in what ways can such an effect be achieved?

Comment: Rather than `Line`, check out [`TubeGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TubeGeometry). A `TubeGeometry` is a `Mesh`, and so can use a `MeshPhongMaterial` (or any other `Mesh`-type materials or shaders).

Comment: Ah awesome, I'll try that later - I knew there must be something like that :)